# Reserved identifiers in Javascript's global namespace

Tags: javascript, browser

If two scripts embedded in a web page need to communicate, one needs some kind of global state, most often a global variable. So while minimizing the amount of global state is always a good idea, one rarely gets along with no global variable.

It is easy to choose a variable name that doesn't clash with what is already standardized, say I choose `foo` or `Foo`. But what about future compatibility? What happens if a new Web API or a new Ecmascript version introduces a `foo` function or a `Foo` object? When a third script is on the page that needs the new standard `Foo` object, it will crash because my scripts have overwritten it with something completely different.

But even if no third-party scripts are on the page, my scripts might run into trouble. Say I have named a global variable `onfoo` and later browser environments introduce a new event `foo` on the global window object. Whenever that new event is fired, my global object `onfoo` will be called...

Thus my question is whether there is any notion of reserved global identifiers in browser environment or whether some names are considered safe. So how should I name my global module? The same goes with other namespaces like custom event names.

Comment: The list of "reserved words" is well established for the published standards, and a draft for ECMAScript 6th edition should contain any additional reserved words, if any. (W3C doesn't control ECMAScript, but it does control the *DOM* API; these DOM global properties aren't technically "reserved identifiers".)

Comment: Trust me, no future version of JavaScript will have a 'foo' keyword. Moreover any future changes will likely be backwards compatible.

Comment: You can always check if a certain attribute is already set on an object. My favorite way to do that is something like `("location" in window)` to check if location is a key in window. This way you could check if a name is taken and give a backup + logging to backend that your variable is taken.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Backwards compatible, yes, but not necessarily compatible with whatever someone decides to write.

Comment: @user2864740: I know that ECMAScript has a number of reseved words, but these are few and the list won't change much. However, these are part of the language and not of the global object.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Sure, foo will likely cause no name clash at any time in the future. But likewise, I don't want to name my global variables `foo`. Read `foo` as a meta-variable.

Comment: @gpgekko: This doesn't help if two scripts need to agree on one global identifier, does it?

Comment: @Marc Then use the terminology (and context) that is *meant*. The DOM standard and ECMAScript standard are related but independent.

Comment: @user2864740: That's why I wrote *reserved identifier* and not *reserved word*, which is an established notion. Please correct me if there is a better notion than my made up *reserved identifier*.

Comment: @Marc If both have the same backup, then yes it does. It just makes sure it doesn't break immediately and gives you some extra time to update the scripts. You can't ever expect a script to stay relevant without maintenance.

Comment: @Marc Global window properties are *neither* reserved identifiers or reserved words. They are simply .. defined properties on the global context; such "global pollution" may be introduced by different standards (or recommendations), separate browser features (e.g. not yet making it into W3C drafts/recs), or by other JavaScript modules/libraries and code.

Comment: @Scimonster that is the meaning of backwards compatible. No changes will be made that break 'wild code'.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If i create a global, let's say `async`. Now what happens if a new JS version adds the default global `async`, with a totally different API? That would either break my code, or another script that depends on the default `async`. No?

Comment: @Scimonster what I'm saying is that this will _never_ happen. When the `async` keyword will be added, it will only be supported _in front_ of function expressions or function declarations and it won't be ambiguous. If it were, then different syntax will be introduced - similar to how generators that use `yield` require you to define `function*(){` instead of `function(){`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not talking about a keyword, and it doesn't seem like the OP is either. I'm referring to, as an example, the Node [`async`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module. As a different example, if i create a `globalStorage` API in a script, and then a later JS standard adds a `globalStorage` API, my script might break other things relying on the default `globalStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

If using a module managing library isn't an option, you'll have to choose between :

- meaningful names: easy to the eye and better for maintenance, they come with a risk of collision (other scripts or new keywords)
- special names:

  `þf  = þf || {};
  þf.yÖ = þf.yÖ || {};`

Nobody will ever add properties to the `þf.yÖ` object, so storing your global data in it is safe. It just looks horrible :)

The best way is to use a module management system without a doubt! 
[This just adds the 'define' global object IIRC](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> So while minimizing the amount of global state is always a good idea, one rarely gets along with no global variable.

However, one can write code so that the global variable name appears only in a few places and can be changed easily if it really becomes necessary. The (revealing) module pattern or even a full-blown dependency management help with that.

> But what about future compatibility?

The thing about the future is that you don't know it. You can however search the web for drafts of upcoming standards, like EcmaScript 6 or W3 HTML5 proposals. There might be some best practises for reducing the probability of clashes however. As you have detected, starting module names with `on` might not be a good idea.

> Is there any notion of reserved global identifiers in browser environment or whether some names are considered safe.

[*Unsafe names*](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/unsafe_names.html) ([1](http://pointedears.de/scripts/faq/cljs/names/unsafe_names.html)) is a quite good start. It might be a little outdated and not exhaustive, but gives a good overview on what you need to watch out for.

> So how should I name my global module? The same goes with other namespaces like custom event names.

Always use a custom and preferably unique prefix for your global names. This can be your project or company name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use global variables. You can rewrite your scripts to accept a "global" object to communicate with. That gives you flexibility to change the communication channel. So while your old code might look like this:

```
//script1
(function(){
   foo.message = "bar";
   // ...
})();

//script2
(function(){
   alert(foo.message);
   // ...
})();
```

Your new code would look like this:

```
var global={};
//script1
(function(foo){
   foo.message = "bar";
   // ...
})(global);

//script2
(function(foo){
   alert(foo.message);
   // ...
})(global);
```

Where your communication channel `global` is explicitly passed in, instead of relying on the window object.

Comment: `global` is created on the window object so you still have a global variable, don't you?

Comment: You don't have to use a global variable. If you took the above code and wrapped it inside a function then global would be function-scoped.

Comment: True, but you can't wrap two embedded scripts on a page in one function (without merging the scripts).

Answer (score -1):

If you must use a global variable, it should preferably be something unique and namespaced. For example, `MarcFoo`. It is extremely unlikely that anyone else will take that name.